# How do I write an rspec Ruby test for this method play_turn?

Tags: ruby, methods, rspec, undefined, nomethoderror

```
class Game
  def start
    @player1 = Player.new("don")
    @player2 = Player.new("tum")
  end

  def player_turn
    if @turn.even? 
      puts "this is #{@player2.name}'s turn"
    else
      puts "this is #{@player1.name}'s turn"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please show what you tried ...

Comment: I already solved it though. Thank you.

Comment: ```ruby
describe Game do
  describe "player_turn" do
      it "shows player two's turn" do
        allow(subject).to receive(:turn) { 2 }
        expect (subject.player_turn).to eql('this is tum's turn')
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think first you are going to have to define the instance variable `@turn`, and how it is incremented. Additionally I would recommend changing the Game#start to #initialize, the test below assumes this.
Then you can check what is output to stdout.

```rb
RSpec.describe Game do
  describe "#player_turn" do
    context 'when the turn is even' do
      let(:game) { Game.new }
      it "tells you it is player 2's turn" do
        expect do
          game.player_turn
        end.to output("this is tum's turn\n").to_stdout
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I posted the question and forgot about it but I solved it.